# How to call a prototype function inside another prototype function without losing context

Tags: javascript

I have this [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBhf6/2/):

```
var MyObj = (function() {
    //Constructor
    var MyObj= function(){
        this.myArray = [1,2,3];
    }

    MyObj.prototype = {
        myFunc: function(){
            alert(this.myArray.toString());                
        },
        myFuncCaller: function(){            
            MyObj.prototype.myFunc();                
        }
    };
    return MyObj;      
})();

var myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.myFunc();

//This line will throw an exception because this.myArray is undefined
myObj.myFuncCaller();
```

​
Why is `this.myArray` undefined?
I know I'm doing something wrong, how would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `this`:

```
this.myFunc();
```

When you call a function in Javascript, `this` is set to the expression you called it on.
In your code, for example, `this` in `myFunc()` is `MyObj.prototype`.